# Titanium: Open location settings page on iOS

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-alloy

How can I open a particular settings screen programically on my Titanium/ Alloy app.

In particular I want to open the `Location Services` settings page found under: `Settings > Privacy > Location Services`.

Note I know how to open the app settings page like so (although I did not see this documented anywhere in the official docs):

Ti.Platform.openURL(Ti.App.iOS.applicationOpenSettingsURL);

However, I do not know how to open any other settings page, such as the 'Location Services' page.

It was possible before using the following code:

```
Ti.Platform.openURL('prefs:root=LOCATION_SERVICES');
```

However, this is no longer possible, since iOS 5.1.